# How can I delete or purge old files on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, timestamp, delete-file, s3cmd, purge

Are there existing solutions to delete any files older than x days?

Comment: For now I will use this solution: `s3cmd ls s3://mybucket/mypath/ |ruby -rdate -ne 'date, time, size, uri = $_.split; days = (Time.now - Date.parse(date).to_time) / 60/60/24; puts uri if days > 2' |xargs s3cmd del`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Amazon has introduced [object expiration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/) recently.

> Amazon S3 Announces Object Expiration
>
> Amazon S3 announced a new
>   feature, Object Expiration that allows you to schedule the deletion of
>   your objects after a pre-defined time period. Using Object Expiration
>   to schedule periodic removal of objects eliminates the need for you 
>   to identify objects for deletion and submit delete requests to Amazon
>   S3.
>
> You can define Object Expiration rules for a set of objects in
>   your bucket. Each  Object Expiration rule allows you to specify a
>   prefix and an expiration period in days. The prefix field (e.g.
>   `logs/`) identifies the object(s) subject to the  expiration rule, and
>   the expiration period specifies the number of days from  creation date
>   (i.e. age) after which object(s) should be removed. Once the objects
>   are past their expiration date, they will be queued for deletion. You
>   will not be billed for storage for objects on or after their
>   expiration date.

Comment: That is quite a blunt tool provided by Amazon; it does what it says on the tin! If you need finer control on how deletion is done, you will have to use the old DELETE method. Other option is to have a up to 1000 different object-expiration rules (and 1000 different prefixes); still you are limited to 1000.

Comment: This does not delete the 'older already present files'. It take effect from the time you create it.

Comment: This rule can be set for the entire bucket but not individual folders within the bucket ?

Comment: @Harshdeep - so not really. "After an Object Expiration rule is added, the rule is applied to objects that already exist in the bucket as well as any new objects added to the bucket after the rule is created." https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/

Comment: Can you specify a time period less than a day? e.g. I'd like objects to expire in 15 min.

Comment: @Slawomir How much time does it take for a new expiration rule to take effect on existing objects in the bucket?

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 5):

Here is some information on how to do it...

*[Lifecycle configuration elements](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html)*

Comment: Link only answers are not *great* They should include some relevant bit of information on what that link provides. This answer becomes useless if the link ever dies. See this post
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/286322

Comment: The OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to implement it using a CloudFormation template:

```
  JenkinsArtifactsBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "jenkins-artifacts"
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: "remove-old-artifacts"
            ExpirationInDays: 3
            NoncurrentVersionExpirationInDays: 3
            Status: Enabled
```

This creates a lifecycle rule as [explained by Ravi Bhatt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984561/how-can-i-delete-or-purge-old-files-on-s3/8985137#8985137).

Read more on that: *[AWS::S3::Bucket Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html)*

How object lifecycle management works: *[Managing your storage lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)*

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS S3 Life cycle rules to expire the files and delete them. All you have to do is select the bucket, click on "Add lifecycle rules" button and configure it and AWS will take care of them for you.

You can refer the below blog post from Joe for step-by-step instructions. It's quite simple actually:

*[Amazon S3 – How to delete files older than x days](https://www.joe0.com/2017/05/24/amazon-s3-how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-days/)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python script to delete N-days old files:

```python
from boto3 import client, Session
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--access_key_id', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--secret_access_key', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--delete_after_retention_days', required=False, default=15)
    parser.add_argument('--bucket', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--prefix', required=False, default="")
    parser.add_argument('--endpoint', required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    access_key_id = args.access_key_id
    secret_access_key = args.secret_access_key
    delete_after_retention_days = int(args.delete_after_retention_days)
    bucket = args.bucket
    prefix = args.prefix
    endpoint = args.endpoint

    # Get current date
    today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

    try:
        # create a connection to Wasabi
        s3_client = client(
            's3',
            endpoint_url=endpoint,
            access_key_id=access_key_id,
            secret_access_key=secret_access_key)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    try:
        # List all the buckets under the account
        list_buckets = s3_client.list_buckets()
    except ClientError:
        # Invalid access keys
        raise Exception("Invalid Access or Secret key")

    # Create a paginator for all objects.
    object_response_paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_object_versions')
    if len(prefix) > 0:
        operation_parameters = {'Bucket': bucket,
                                'Prefix': prefix}
    else:
        operation_parameters = {'Bucket': bucket}

    # Instantiate temp variables.
    delete_list = []
    count_current = 0
    count_non_current = 0

    print("$ Paginating bucket " + bucket)
    for object_response_itr in object_response_paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters):
        for version in object_response_itr['Versions']:
            if version["IsLatest"] is True:
                count_current += 1
            elif version["IsLatest"] is False:
                count_non_current += 1
            if (today - version['LastModified']).days > delete_after_retention_days:
                delete_list.append({'Key': version['Key'], 'VersionId': version['VersionId']})

    # Print objects count
    print("-" * 20)
    print("$ Before deleting objects")
    print("$ current objects: " + str(count_current))
    print("$ non-current objects: " + str(count_non_current))
    print("-" * 20)

    # Delete objects 1000 at a time
    print("$ Deleting objects from bucket " + bucket)
    for i in range(0, len(delete_list), 1000):
        response = s3_client.delete_objects(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Delete={
                'Objects': delete_list[i:i + 1000],
                'Quiet': True
            }
        )
        print(response)

    # Reset counts
    count_current = 0
    count_non_current = 0

    # Paginate and recount
    print("$ Paginating bucket " + bucket)
    for object_response_itr in object_response_paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket):
        if 'Versions' in object_response_itr:
            for version in object_response_itr['Versions']:
                if version["IsLatest"] is True:
                    count_current += 1
                elif version["IsLatest"] is False:
                    count_non_current += 1

    # Print objects count
    print("-" * 20)
    print("$ After deleting objects")
    print("$ current objects: " + str(count_current))
    print("$ non-current objects: " + str(count_non_current))
    print("-" * 20)
    print("$ task complete")
```

And here is how I run it:

```
python s3_cleanup.py --aws_access_key_id="access-key" --aws_secret_access_key="secret-key-here" --endpoint="https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com" --bucket="ondemand-downloads" --prefix="" --delete_after_retention_days=5
```

If you want to delete files only from a specific folder, then use the `prefix` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PowerShell script to delete object expired after `x days`.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$BUCKET_NAME,             # Name of the Bucket

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$OBJ_PATH,                # Key prefix of s3 object (directory path)

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$EXPIRY_DAYS              # Number of days to expire
)

$CURRENT_DATE = Get-Date
$OBJECTS = Get-S3Object $BUCKET_NAME -KeyPrefix $OBJ_PATH
Foreach($OBJ in $OBJECTS){
    IF($OBJ.key -ne $OBJ_PATH){
        IF(($CURRENT_DATE - $OBJ.LastModified).Days -le $EXPIRY_DAYS){
            Write-Host "Deleting Object= " $OBJ.key
            Remove-S3Object -BucketName $BUCKET_NAME -Key $OBJ.Key -Force
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This script does not work for the scenario I wanted which was to delete objects older than the specified time. The line  IF(($CURRENT_DATE - $OBJ.LastModified).Days -le $EXPIRY_DAYS)... should actually be  IF(($CURRENT_DATE - $OBJ.LastModified).Days -ge $EXPIRY_DAYS)...